# Sequel gem copy database to another with username and password

Tags: ruby, sequel, sequel-gem

From the [section](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/doc/bin_sequel.rdoc#copy-databases) to copy another use is to use

```
sequel -C mysql://host1/database postgres://host2/database2
```

Is there a way to include username and password for both databases. 
    Tried with no luck

```
sequel -C mysql://user:password@host1/database postgres://user2:password2@host2/database2
```

Answer (score 0):

The usernames and passwords are stored in the user database. You first need to setup a user on your target database. Before that you can't copy anything to it. Copying the user database from mysql to postgres is not going to work either imho so you will have to setup your user manually first.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your question I was able to get this working with sqlite3 to postgres. In my case, I don't need a password in the input file.

```
sequel -C sqlite://db/development.sqlite3 postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost/mydb
```

Before trying the `sequel` gem, I tried a sqlite dump and then a load with `psql` but that failed on text fields. I had made the appropriate changes to booleans and datetime. I could not load `pgloader` on my old mac, so I can't speak for that option. Sequel worked instantly.